# Disable Inputs on Dropdown Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, event-handling

So I'm working on a webform right now and I need to disable all forms of input once one  has a specific value. Is there an easy way to handle as soon as that dropdown gets to that value? 
Currently I'm doing this:

```
setInterval('check()', 5000);
function check() {
// Disable all fields if the answer was no.
if ($("#has_contract").val() == 0) {
    disable();
}
function disable() {
    $("#inputs *").prop('disabled', true);
    alert("There is no contract, please get a contract.");
}
```

has_contract is my  element, and #inputs contains all of the inputs I would like to disable if #has_contract's value is 0.**

But this isn't ideal. 
Is there a better way to do this rather than constantly checking every X amount of seconds?

Comment: What kind of element is #has_contract?  A `<select>` or a text field or ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking for the value every 5 seconds, you can check the value on change.

```
// collect elements
var $hasContract = $("#has_contract");
var $inputs = $("#inputs input");

// on change, check the input
$hasContract.on('change', checkForm);

// Checks the hasContract input for a value
// of 0. If it does, disable the form.
function checkForm() {
    if($hasContract.val() == 0) {
        $inputs.attr('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

Also, when you use setTimeout, or setInterval you don't have to use a string. Javascript supports passing functions as variables. See below.

```
// Do NOT do this
setInterval('check()', 5000);

// Do this instead
setInterval(check, 5000);

// or this
setInterval(function() {

    //preform the check...

}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely certain that I understand your requirements, but would this work for you?

The below assumes that `#has_contract` is a `<select>` element:

```
$("#has_contract").change(function() {
    if ($("#has_contract").val() == 0) disable();
});
```

Comment: That sounds good, would the call on disable() only effect #has_contract?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should cache the elements as a variable and then run the function against that variable.

```
var myInputs
$(document).ready(function(){
   myInputs = $("#inputs input"); // or '#inputs *' if you're excited about the asterix
});
```

Second thing, if I'm reading your setup correctly, you're going to pop an alert box every 5 seconds until the user has selected 'yes' to the contract. That will get QUITE annoying and they probably won't want to open a contract with you after that.

Without actually seeing your page, I'd imagine a better solution would be to check for the contract=yes when the click a submit button of some sort on the page.

```
$('#mySubmitButton').click(function(){
  if ($("#has_contract").val() == 0) {
    disable();
  }
});
```

But maybe go one step further, what you really want to do is give them access to the form once they agree to the contract. So you should have the form disabled by default (coded into the html that everything is disabled), and attach a function to the 'yes' button that enables the form. Additionally, you can attach a function to the 'no' button that re-disables it, if they had previously clicked 'yes'.

```
$('#myYesBtn').click(function(){
  myInputs.prop('disabled', false);
});

$('#myNoBtn').click(function(){
  myInputs.prop('disabled', true);
});
```